# Multiple synchronized CKEditor instances on the same page?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm working on a document-editing application using CKEditor, where the user can open multiple documents side-by-side in a pair of editor instances.

Most of the time, the user will be editing two different documents, but it's also possible that the two editor instances might contain different views of the same document. That makes things tricky, since I'd like to changes in one editor instance to be immediately reflected in the other instance.

Without hacking the CKEditor core, is something like that possible?

If not, would it be possible to write a plugin that would provide that kind of functionality?

What about if I was willing to get into the core code and hack around a bit? How difficult would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very similar case to a collaborative editing like Google Docs allows. The only differences are that you won't need to synchronize this via network and that it's very unlikely (if not impossible) that the same documents will be modified by two users at the same time. This makes things simpler... a little bit.

A year ago me and my colleague (we are both CKEditor core devs) took part in [Node.JS Knockout](http://nodeknockout.com/) and our plan was to create a collaborative editor based on CKEditor. It was only 48h, so the result is not impressive, but it worked. The source code is [here](https://github.com/nko3/epic-fail).

The main problem you'll have is applying changes from editor A to editor B **without breaking a caret position in editor B**. Basically, you cannot just take data from editor A and set them in editor B, because everything in editor B will be reset including scroll position and caret. Unless this is not a problem, but I assume it is.

So you would need to:

- either find a nice algorithm for extracting changes (like `diff`, but working on a DOM tree, not an HTML string) made in editor A and an algorithm to apply them to editor B (and this is what we implemented on Node.JS Knockout),
- or find a way to guess caret position after resetting data in editor B; for example you can remember the caret context in editor B before setting data and try to find it in data that will be loaded.

Both ways are doable, but the first way will give better results if you'll implement it well. However, if your you don't know enough about DOM and `contenteditable`, then this task may overwhelm you. In this case I would advise to block possibility of opening one document twice.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how I anticipated implementing it, though I hadn't imagined there would already be a github repo. Thanks!!